# How to set the default schema for psql when connecting to a specific db?

Tags: linux, postgresql, psql

I use [`psql`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/app-psql.html) to connect to multiple databases which contain multiple schemas. I usually use just one schema per db. Is it possible to set the default schema for a particular db via some `psql` config option or envariable?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use a `service file`:

https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/libpq-pgservice.html

> 34.17. The Connection Service file

> The connection service file allows libpq connection parameters to be associated with a single service name. That service name can then be specified in a libpq connection string, and the associated settings will be used. This allows connection parameters to be modified without requiring a recompile of the libpq-using application. The service name can also be specified using the PGSERVICE environment variable.

See rest of page for where to create the file for user or system wide use.

As example for setting `search_path` for specific database:

```
[test_db]
dbname=test
host=localhost
port=5432
user=aklaver
options=-csearch_path=utility
```

Usage.

Without service file:

```
psql -d test -U aklaver 

test(5432)=> show search_path ;
                      search_path                      
-------------------------------------------------------
 public,history,main,utility,timeclock,table_templates
```

With service file:

```
psql "service=test_db"

test(5432)=> show search_path ;
 search_path 
-------------
 utility
(1 row)
```

Then you are not altering the `search_path` for the database for all connections, just `psql` when using the service file.

UPDATE

The above did not work in the OP's case as they where connecting through `PgBouncer`. As an alternative the solution in @LaurenzAlbe's answer was suggested. That is to do:

`alter database <some_db> set search_path = <some_path>`

Per [ALTER DATABASE](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-alterdatabase.html).

Comment: Using a service file works fine for all the above parameters, except for `options=-csearch_path=<schema>`. Any idea how to fix this? I'm using `psql (14.11 (Homebrew), server 14.5)`

Comment: @planetp. Define not works.

Comment: `search_path` remains unchanged for the connection.

Comment: Are you sure: 1) You are looking at the same database. 2) search_path is not being set else where. Run this query `select name, setting, source, sourcefile, sourceline from pg_settings where name = 'search_path';` to verify.

Answer (score 1):

You can set the parameter `search_path` for each database:

```
ALTER DATABASE mydb1 SET search_path = myschema1, public;
```

Answer (score 0):

If you need something more specific than Laurenz's answer, you can restrict the setting to just your own user with:

```
ALTER USER current_user in database <somedatabase> set search_path to <somepath>;
```